# Read out JavaScript onClick function body and use it for another onClick

Tags: javascript, events

I try to copy an onClick function from an image to an span object.
But I don't get it.

I have tried it directly with `onClick=img.onClick`, `onClick=new Function(img.onClick)` and more.

```
if (img.onclick != undefined)
{
    var imgClick = img.onclick;
    strNewHTML = strNewHTML + " onMouseOver=\"this.style.background"
    + "= '#cecece'\" onMouseOut=\"this.style.background = ''\" onclick=\""+imgClick+"\">";
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
span.onclick= img.onclick;
```

JavaScript is case-sensitive and DOM event handler properties are all lower-case.

edit:

```
if (img.onclick != undefined) {
    strNewHTML = strNewHTML + " onMouseOver=\"this.style.background"
    + "= '#cecece'\" onMouseOut=\"this.style.background = ''\" onclick=\""+imgClick+"\">";
}
```

Well that's a completely different thing. You're creating an HTML string. But the `onclick` DOM property contains a `function` object. `function` objects can't be added into strings. (They would get converted to what you get if you call `somefunction.toString()`, which is not something that will work as an event handler.)

If you wanted to fetch the textual value of the `onclick` attribute to add into HTML, you'd have to do it with the `span.getAttribute('onclick')` method. *But* that won't work in IE due to bugs in its implementation of `getAttribute`, so you'd have to resort to `span.getAttributeNode('onclick').value`. And then when you added it into the HTML string, you'd have to HTML-escape it, so that any `<`, `&` and `"` characters in it came out as `&lt;` etc., otherwise they'll break the markup.

However, this is really ugly; **don't do it**. In reality, HTML string-slinging invariably sucks. Especially when you've got JavaScript code inside HTML inside a JavaScript string. The escaping rules get insane and if you make a mistake escaping content that comes from user input, you've given yourself a cross-site-scripting security hole.

Instead, use DOM methods. This takes all the escaping out of the equation and it's generally more readable than hacked-together HTML markup strings. Then you can freely assign `onclick` to whatever function you like. eg.:

```
var span= document.createElement('span');
if (img.onclick)
    span.onclick= img.onclick;
span.onmouseover= function() {
    this.style.background= '#CECECE';
};
span.onmouseout= function() {
    this.style.background= '';
};

someparentelement.appendChild(span);
```

Also consider replacing the mouseover/mouseout with a simple CSS `:hover` rule, for maintainability. The only browser that still needs help with `:hover` is IE6.

Comment: `span.onclick=img.onclick;` ... This is the correct answer. Functions are first-class objects in javascript.

Comment: IE6 sucks.
And I have to write a PNG correction and there I need the implementation of the copy of onClick.